# IOS TableViewCell exc_bad_access autorelease error

Tags: ios, memory-management, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have a problem on the memory management of a tableviewcell (**exc_bad_access**).
One of mine **tableviewcell** include a uiwebview that loads asynchronous html data (**loadHTMLString** method) and the current controller is set as its delegate.
When i pop tableviewcontroller from my navigation controller too fast the app crashes.
In my opinion this is the reason why it fails:
 - if cell deallocs before the controller => all ok, delegate is still live and i can even set its delegate to nil in its own dealloc method 
 - if cell deallocs after the controller (i guess because table view cells are autoreleased) => the app crashes because its delegate it's still set to the deallocated controller

Any idea how to correctly solve this??
Thank you..

CODE in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
...
CustomTableViewCell * cCell = (CustomTableViewCell*)cell; 
cCell.myWebView.delegate = self; 
[[cCell myWebView] loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
....
```

Comment: Could you give a code snippet?

Comment: TO check your guess you can add NSLog at cell and viewController classes `dealloc`, i'm sure autoreleased cell is deallocated before the controller.

Comment: App crashes before NSLOG in the cell dealloc method is called. I guess autorelease pool comes after controller is deallocated. Obviously i tap back button really really fast as controller is pushed. If i comment "[[cCell myWebView] loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];" everything works fine..

Comment: Post the code for the cell. Something else is amiss here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add [stopLoading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stopLoading) at cell deallocation before releasing the web view.

Comment: @user1427835 Post the backtrace please.

Comment: *** -[MyCustomViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5c607f0
[unknown](gdb)

Comment: @user1427835 is this controller the delegate of your webViews ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but it never really got solved, and I just ran into it myself.

This happened to me: The view controller would crash when a cell was loaded with a web view who had the cell as it's delegate.  UIWebView's documentation states that a web view's delegate should be set to nil before it is deallocated.  This seems to also be true for reused table view cells.

My solution: override these in your custom cell:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
    {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.myWebView.delegate = nil;
    [self.myWebView stopLoading];
    }

- (void)dealloc
    {
    self.myWebView.delegate = nil;
    [self.myWebView stopLoading];
    }
```

This fixed it for me.